# Running two bat files from powershell and returns their outputs separately

Tags: powershell

I want to start two bat files with Powershell Start-Job cmdlet  and to be able to get their output 
and keep them running until user press any key but unfortunately I get the following error:

```
[localhost] There is an error processing data from the background process. Error reported: Cannot process an element
with node type "Text". Only Element and EndElement node types are supported..
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
```

Here is my power-shell implementation.

```
$workingDir = (Get-Location)

$first = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($workingDir)
    $firstPath = -join($workingDir, "\first\batFileName.bat")
    Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath ($firstPath) -PassThru
} -ArgumentList $workingDir

$second =  Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($workingDir)
    $secondPath = -join($workingDir, "\second\batFileName.bat")
    Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath ($secondPath) -PassThru
} -ArgumentList $workingDir
Receive-Job -Job $second
Receive-Job -Job $first
Write-Host "The processes are running"
Write-Host "Press any key to kill them..."
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
Stop-Job $first
Stop-Job $second
```

May you help me to find what is the problem and point me how to implement this properly?

Edit:

I managed to implement something which works in similar way. 
This example can be downloaded here:
https://github.com/gonaumov/batWithPowerShell
It runs two jobs with first.bat and second.bat but I still have
some problems. After some time I start to get 
only messages from the second bat file.

Comment: what do the bats do and what do they look like

Comment: Prefer to not share them. They just run some another processes and returns some output. Some java processes java ... some options.